# Как удалить повторяющиеся строки

Tags: c#

Есть следующая таблица:

```
price|text
2    |one
3    |one
6    |two
4    |two
```

Как мне найти дублирующиеся строки по колонке `text` и одновременно  сравнить их по колонке цене и с наибольшей ценой удалить?

Мой код для удаления дубликатов по полонке `text`:

```
 foreach (DataRow row in price_table.Rows
                               .Cast<DataRow>()
                               .GroupBy(row => row["text"])
                               .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)   
                               .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1))
                              )
        {
        row.Delete();

        }
    price_table.AcceptChanges();
```

Спасибо! немного подправил получилось то что надо !

```
foreach (DataRow row in source_price.Rows
                           .Cast<DataRow>()
                          .GroupBy(row => row["text"])
                          .Where(g => g.Count() > 1) 

                          .Select(g => g.OrderBy(r => r.Field<string>("Price")).Last())
                          )
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, напишите свой вопрос на русском языке.

Comment: А какой тип у `price_table` и каким фреймфорком для работы с таблицами вы пользуетесь, нам нужно догадаться самостоятельно?

Comment: @VladD похоже что обычный `DataTable`, судя по тому что `DataRow`

Comment: @Aleksandr воспользуйтесь [техподдержкой](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact) для объединения учетных записей.

Answer (score 4):

Сгруппируйте по тексту, отсортируйте каждую группу по цене, и выберите по одному элементу из группы:

```
foreach (DataRow row in price_table.Rows
                              .Cast<DataRow>()
                              .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("text"))
                              .Select(g => g.OrderBy(r => r.Field<int>("Price")).First()))
{
    row.Delete();

}
price_table.AcceptChanges();
```